# Get object inside partial View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

Friends,

I have a View page called "OtherDatas.cshtml" and i need to render a PartialView inside her. So, to make this, i need to check if the object inside partialView is null or not. If not, the partialView Appears. How can i get the object inside the partialView? Here is my code:

OtherDatas.cshtml:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        @{
            if (//I need to check the object inside ){
                Html.Partial("~/Views/Outrosdados/Search.cshtml");
            }
            else
            {
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th style="min-width:130px;">Mês</th>
                    <th style="min-width:80px;">Amortização</th>
                    <th style="min-width:100px;">Recebimento do Mês</th>
                    <th style="min-width:100px;">Atraso</th>
                    <th style="min-width:100px;">DAMP3</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            }
        }
    </div>
```

PartialView Search.html:

```
@model TB_DADOS_MANUAIS
@using EixoX.Html;
@using Gestão.Models;
@using System.Globalization;
@{
    List<TB_OUTROS_DADOS> od = (List<TB_OUTROS_DADOS>)ViewData["outrosDados"];
Bootstrap3Presenter<TB_OUTROS_DADOS> presenter = 
Bootstrap3Presenter<TB_OUTROS_DADOS>.GetInstance("pt-BR");
ViewBag.Title = "Outros Dados";
```

}

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th style="min-width:130px;">Mês</th>
        <th style="min-width:80px;">Amortização</th>
        <th style="min-width:100px;">Recebimento do Mês</th>
        <th style="min-width:100px;">Atraso</th>
        <th style="min-width:100px;">DAMP3</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (TB_OUTROS_DADOS dados in od){
        <tr>
<td>@dados.DT_MES_UTILIZACAO.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR"))</td>
    <td><span class="money" />@dados.VL_AMORTIZACAO</td>
    <td><span class="money" />@dados.VL_RECEBIMENTO_MES</td>
    <td><span class="money" />@dados.VL_ATRASO</td>
    <td><span class="money" />@dados.VL_DAMP3</td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I need to check inside of the 'foreach' if i have some 'TB_OUTROS_DADOS' inside the 'od' list.

Thanks!

Comment: Add the If statement that you have in the main page to the partial view. In the partial you can check whether the object exists or not. If it exists, return the data from the partial view, otherwise, return what you currently have in your else statement in the main view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that in this way.
Pass List<> as model to you parent view or declare this list in same way like in partial view then do check, and if it is good pass it to partial view. 
In this way:

```
@{
    List<TB_OUTROS_DADOS> od = (List<TB_OUTROS_DADOS>)ViewData["outrosDados"];
    <div class="table-responsive">
            @{
                if (od.Count > 0){
                    Html.Partial("~/Views/Outrosdados/Search.cshtml",od);
                }
                else
                {
                <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th style="min-width:130px;">Mês</th>
                    <th style="min-width:80px;">Amortização</th>
                    <th style="min-width:100px;">Recebimento do Mês</th>
                    <th style="min-width:100px;">Atraso</th>
                    <th style="min-width:100px;">DAMP3</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            }
        }
    </div>
```

And in PartialView

```
@model List<TB_OUTROS_DADOS>
@using EixoX.Html;
@using Gestão.Models;
@using System.Globalization;
@{

Bootstrap3Presenter<TB_OUTROS_DADOS> presenter = 
Bootstrap3Presenter<TB_OUTROS_DADOS>.GetInstance("pt-BR");
ViewBag.Title = "Outros Dados";
}

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th style="min-width:130px;">Mês</th>
        <th style="min-width:80px;">Amortização</th>
        <th style="min-width:100px;">Recebimento do Mês</th>
        <th style="min-width:100px;">Atraso</th>
        <th style="min-width:100px;">DAMP3</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (TB_OUTROS_DADOS dados in Model){
        <tr>
<td>@dados.DT_MES_UTILIZACAO.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR"))</td>
    <td><span class="money" />@dados.VL_AMORTIZACAO</td>
    <td><span class="money" />@dados.VL_RECEBIMENTO_MES</td>
    <td><span class="money" />@dados.VL_ATRASO</td>
    <td><span class="money" />@dados.VL_DAMP3</td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for me! I think i've trying to make the impossible haha